# Как сделать правильный переход c tableViewCell к ViewController в Parse по objectID?

Tags: ios, swift, parse.com

Столкнулся с проблемой в Parse.com. Данные, которые находятся в одной строчке и имеют один ObjectId не правильно отображаются. Когда делал через for in, то в одной ячейке при открытии эти данные отображаются по кругу, а rjulf убрал функцию for in, теперь, открывая разные ячейки данных, с первой строки показывает. Как сделать так, чтобы по строчке показывались данные? Пожалуйста помогите...

Вот мой код Parse:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class DetailTennisViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageTennis: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var outClose: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleTennis: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textTennis: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var progTennis: UILabel!

    @IBAction func closeOut(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    var tenises = Tennis()

    func configureButton() {
        outClose.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * outClose.bounds.size.width
        outClose.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.imageTennis.image = imageTennis.image
        loadTennis()
        configureButton()
    }

    func loadTennis () {

        let qwery = PFQuery(className: "tennis")

        qwery.getFirstObjectInBackground() { (object,error) ->Void in
            if error == nil {
                self.textTennis.text = object!["textTen"] as? String
                self.progTennis.text = object!["progTen"] as? String
                self.titleTennis.text = object!["titleTen"] as? String
                let imageFile = object!["tenImage"] as? PFFile
                imageFile?.getDataInBackground() { (data:Data?, error:Error?)->Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        if let imageData = data {
                            self.imageTennis.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Дам подсказку, посмотрите в сторону метода  `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) `

Comment: Виталий я уже пробывал и даже на форуме одном с парнем общались.Это проблема в этом коде qwery.Я вот вопросы перечитываю на иностранном сайте

Comment: Ну так получается вы всегда получаете только первый объект: у вас же даже тут это сказанно  qwery.getFirstObjectInBackground(). В чем проблема то? Изучите API.

Comment: Я вот изучаю и учусь.Я и так знаю, ну суть проблемы не в этом .Я вот на английской версии нашел пару ситуаций похожих...

Answer (score 1):

завяжите на ячейку **objectId**, при переходе передавайте его во вью контроллер и в методе `loadTennis()` поменяйте `getFirstObjectInBackground()`  на `getObjectInBackgroundWithId()` [подробно про метод](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#/c:objc(cs)PFQuery(im)getObjectInBackgroundWithId:)

и еще я бы обернул все что обновляет UI в методе `getFirstObjectInBackground()` в блок `DispatchQueue.main.async {}`

Пример использования `getObjectInBackgroundWithId()`
[image]

и сам код

```
let qwery = PFQuery(className: "tennis")
var object: PFObject?
do {
    object = try qwery.getObjectWithId("objId")
    // или сдесь обрабатываем обьект
} catch let error {
    dump(error)
}
if object != nil {
    // do somesing
}

// или так
qwery.getObjectInBackground(withId: "object", block: { (object , error) in
    if error != nil {
        dump(error!)
    } else {
         // do somesing
    }
})
```

**Parse 1.15.3** установлен через [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Parse)

Comment: Знаете пытаюсь добавить этот метод(getObjectInBackgroundWithId()) его не в списке, он не подходит мне.Много разных других выдает.

Comment: не знаю откуда вы его пытаетесь добавить, я поставил парс через йоды и все прекрасно работает, добавляю скрин кода в ответ

Comment: Через поды * , опечатка

Comment: Спасибо, Андрей пробую.Знаешь я чета писал и пробовал, варианты и потом нашел причину и у меня объекты стали загружаться))), а сейчас увидел блин по кругу или наоборот .